# How to scrape data from Bloomberg's website with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

## Background

Disclaimer: I am a beginner, please bare with my - most plausibly wrong - code.

I want to update currency pairs' value (**PREV CLOSE**) with a button-enabled-VBA macro. My Excel worksheet contains FX pairs (e.g. USDGBP) on **column G:G** which are then used to run a FOR loop for every pair in the column.

The value would then be stored in **column I:I**

Right now, the problem according to the Debugger lies in one line of code that I will highlight below

## Sources

I got some inspiration from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxmRjh-S2Ms&t=1050s - notably 17:34 onwards - but I want my code to work for multiple websites at the press of a button.

## I have tried the following code

```
Public Sub Auto_FX_update_BMG()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'My computer is not very fast, thus I use this line of
                                        'code to save some computing power and time

    Dim internet_object As InternetExplorer
    Dim i As Integer

         For i = 3 To Sheets(1).Cells(3, 7).End(xlDown).Row
              FX_Pair = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7)

              Set internet_object = New InternetExplorer
              internet_object.Visible = True
              internet_object.navigate "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/" & FX_Pair & ":CUR"

              Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

              internet_object.document.getElementsByClassName("class")(0).getElementsByTagName ("value__b93f12ea")  '--> DEBUGGER PROBLEM
                                                                                                                    'My goal here is to "grab" the PREV CLOSE
                                                                                                                    'value from the website
                    With ActiveSheet
                        .Range(Cells(i, 9)).Value = HTML_element.Children(0).textContent
                    End With

             Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 9)).Copy   'Not sure if these 2 lines are unnecesary
             ActiveSheet.Paste

         Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

## Expected Result

WHEN I enter "USDGBP" on a cell on **column G:G**, the macro would go to https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/EURGBP:CUR and "grab" the PREV CLOSE value of 0.8732 (using today's value) and insert it in the respective row of **column I:I**

As of now, I am just facing the debugger without much idea on how to solve the problem.

Comment: You've got multiple issues going on here... `Set internet_object = New InternetExplorer` needs to be outside your loop. `.Range(Cells(i, 9)).Value` should just be `Cells(i, 9).Value`. That ` internet_object.document.getElementsByClassName` line needs to be part of an action, like `Range("A1").Value =  internet_object.document.getElementsByClassName...` etc.

Comment: I don't have time to look at this today, but I'll see if I can help you fix this tomorrow using `.querySelector` instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class selectors in a loop. The pattern

```
.previousclosingpriceonetradingdayago .value__b93f12ea
```

specifies to get child elements with class  `value__b93f12ea` having parent with class `previousclosingpriceonetradingdayago`. The "." in front is a css [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) and is a faster way of selecting as modern browsers are optimized for css. The space between the two classes is a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator). querySelector returns the first match for this pattern from the webpage html document.

This matches on the page:

[image]

You can see the parent child relationship and classes again here:

```html
<section class="dataBox previousclosingpriceonetradingdayago numeric">
    <header class="title__49417cb9"><span>Prev Close</span></header>
    <div class="value__b93f12ea">0.8732</div>
</section>
```

---

N.B. If you are a Bloomberg customer look into their [APIs](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/). Additionally, it is very likely you can get this same info from other dedicated APIs which will allow for much faster and more reliable xhr requests.

---

**VBA (Internet Explorer):**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim pairs(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long, ie As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ws
        pairs = Application.Transpose(.Range("G2:G" & .Cells(.rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Value) ' assumes pairs start in row 2
    End With
    Dim results()
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(pairs))
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        For i = LBound(pairs) To UBound(pairs)
            .Navigate2 "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/" & pairs(i) & ":CUR", False
             While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
             results(i) = .document.querySelector(".previousclosingpriceonetradingdayago .value__b93f12ea").innerText
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    ws.Cells(2, "I").Resize(UBound(results), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)
End Sub
```

---

For very limited numbers of requests (as leads to blocking) you could use xhr request and regex out the value. I assume pairs are in sheet one and start from G2. I also assume there are no empty cells or invalid pairs in column G up to an including last pair to search for. Otherwise, you will need to develop the code to handle this.

Try regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/OAyq30/1/)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim re As Object, pairs(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long, s As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With ws
        pairs = Application.Transpose(.Range("G2:G" & .Cells(.rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Value) ' assumes pairs start in row 2
    End With
    Dim results()
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(pairs))
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(pairs) To UBound(pairs)
            .Open "GET", "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/" & pairs(i) & ":CUR", False
            .send
            s = .responseText
            results(i) = GetCloseValue(re, s, "previousClosingPriceOneTradingDayAgo%22%3A(.*?)%2")
        Next
    End With
    ws.Cells(2, "I").Resize(UBound(results), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)
End Sub
Public Function GetCloseValue(ByVal re As Object, inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String 'https://regex101.com/r/OAyq30/1
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern
        If .test(inputString) Then
            GetCloseValue = .Execute(inputString)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetCloseValue = "Not found"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your input @QHarr. The code works well on its own, but unfortunately I have another 'Private Sub' that registers a timestamp each time values in a certain column change.

Basically, the latter works with 'application.undo' in order to undo the most recent change to compare it to the new one.

When I launch your code, the Debugger prompts me towards this 'application.undo' and I have not found much information online. 
Would you know why both macros clash?

Comment: Hi @QHarr. My apologies, I completely forgot to loop you in: I created a new post as you recommended --> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189727/my-two-macros-clash-i-e-they-cannot-operate-simultaneously). What I have done for now is just to separate both Subs in different Workbooks, and I manually Copy and Paste the results to "bridge" the data. I have tried to Output the data with "debug.print [variable; in this case "results"]" - which in my opinion would be one of the best alternatives - but I arrive to a Type mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code: 
But before make sure to add 2 reference by going to Tools> References > then look for Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft Internet Controls

This code works upon using your example.

```
Sub getPrevCloseValue()

Dim ie As Object

Dim mySh As Worksheet
Set mySh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim colG_Value As String
Dim prev_value As String


For a = 3 To mySh.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    colG_Value = mySh.Range("G" & a).Value

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/" & colG_Value & ":CUR"
    Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")) 'activate if having problem with delay

    For Each sect In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("section")
        If sect.className = "dataBox previousclosingpriceonetradingdayago numeric" Then
            prev_value = sect.getElementsByTagName("div")(0).innerText
            mySh.Range("I" & a).Value = prev_value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sect

Next a
```

I have a video tutorial for basic web automation using vba which include web data scraping and other commands, please check the link below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jejwXID4OH4&t=700s