# My two macros "clash", i.e. they cannot operate simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba

## Background

I have 2 macros in one of my worksheets that **i)** get the Previous Close price from Bloomberg's website straight into the worksheet [trigered by a button] (Cells H3:downwards) and **ii)** the other registers a timestamp if this new value causes a change in a formula located in cells K3:downwards. Then, if there is any change, the time in which it happened will be registered in the columns to the immediate right of column H.

My problem lies in that when I press the button to launch Macro i), the debugger pops "Run time error 1004. Method 'undo' of Object'_application' failed " causing Macro ii) to stop working (i.e. to stop registering the time in which there was a change in value in the column of interest). The line of code highlighted by the debugger is "Application.undo"

To be honest, I am a bit lost on the process.

## This is the code

Disclaimer: Most of the comments are there to educate myself on how the code actually works. Many thanks to everyone who contributed to both Subs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim rMonitored As Range
    Dim MonitoredCell As Range
    Dim vSelected As Variant
    Dim aNewValues As Variant
    Dim ixFormulaCell As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rMonitored = Me.Columns("K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rMonitored Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'No formula cells in column K

    Application.EnableEvents = False    'Disable events to prevent infinite calc loop
    Set vSelected = Selection           'Remember current selection (it may not be a range)

    'Prepare the array that will store the new values, the cells those values are in, and whether or not there was a change
    ReDim aNewValues(1 To rMonitored.Cells.Count, 1 To 3)
        'Column1 = new value
        'Column2 = cell address
        'Column3 = did value change?

    'Get the new value for each formula in column K
    ixFormulaCell = 0
    For Each MonitoredCell In rMonitored.Cells  'The formula cells may not be in a contiguous range
        ixFormulaCell = ixFormulaCell + 1
        aNewValues(ixFormulaCell, 1) = MonitoredCell.Value  'Store the new value
        Set aNewValues(ixFormulaCell, 2) = MonitoredCell    'Store the cell address
    Next MonitoredCell

    Application.Undo    'This will undo the most recent change, which allows us to compare the new vs old to check for formula updates

    ixFormulaCell = 0
    For Each MonitoredCell In rMonitored.Cells
        ixFormulaCell = ixFormulaCell + 1
        'Check if the formula result is different
        If MonitoredCell.Value <> aNewValues(ixFormulaCell, 1) Then
            'Formula result found to be different, record that
            'We can't put the timestamp in now because we still have to redo the most recent change
            aNewValues(ixFormulaCell, 3) = True
        End If
    Next MonitoredCell

    Application.Undo    'Redo the most recent change to put worksheet back in the new state
    '--> THE LINE OF CODE ABOVE IS WHAT THE DEBUGGER POINTS TO

    'Now that we've completed our comparison and have re-done the most recent change, check what did change and put in a timestamp in the next empty cell in same row
    For ixFormulaCell = LBound(aNewValues, 1) To UBound(aNewValues, 1)
        'Check for formula result change
        If aNewValues(ixFormulaCell, 3) Then
            'Formula result change found, get next empty cell in same row
            With Me.Cells(aNewValues(ixFormulaCell, 2).Row, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
                'Next empty cell found, put in the current datetime stamp and format it
                .Value = Now
                .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        End If
    Next ixFormulaCell

    vSelected.Select                'Re-select the remembered selection so that this operation is invisible to users
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'Re-enable events so that the next calculation can be monitored for formula changes in cells of interest

End Sub
Public Sub test()

    Dim re As Object, pairs(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long, s As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With ws
        pairs = Application.Transpose(.Range("G3:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Value) ' assumes pairs start in row 3
    End With

    Dim results()
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(pairs))

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(pairs) To UBound(pairs)
            .Open "GET", "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/" & pairs(i) & ":CUR", False
            .send
            s = .responseText
            results(i) = GetCloseValue(re, s, "previousClosingPriceOneTradingDayAgo%22%3A(.*?)%2")
        Next
    End With

    ws.Cells(3, "I").Resize(UBound(results), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)

End Sub
Public Function GetCloseValue(ByVal re As Object, inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String 'https://regex101.com/r/OAyq30/1

    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern

        If .test(inputString) Then
            GetCloseValue = .Execute(inputString)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetCloseValue = "Not found"
        End If

    End With

End Function
```

## Expected output

I would like both Macros to work simultaneously.

Comment: VBA can't run anything *simultaneously*. You have one single thread to work with. You can do *asynchronous*, but that will still only ever execute one line of code at any given point in time.

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with `Application.Undo` failing though.

Comment: Per the MSDN, `Application.Undo` must be the first line of code and only undoes the last user action https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.undo

Comment: Whenever VBA makes any change to a worksheet or workbook, the undo history gets cleared and therefore `Application.Undo` will no longer be viable.  Because your `test` sub is making a change to the worksheet (by writing its results to cells), the Undo issue is being encountered which is causing the `Worksheet_Calculate` to fail.  The only workaround I can think of would be to instead output the results elsehwere (like debug.print or a text file) and then copy/paste the results manually to preserve the Undo history.

Comment: Another option is to use a public array to store the values of the "monitored" cells. You'll have to populate the array with the Workbook_Open event and update it inside the Calculate event.